# Function can't take tuple inputs?

Tags: python

My function `read(one,two,three)` takes 3 inputs.

I have a tuple of tuples and I want to apply the function on the tuples inside, e.g.:

```
a = ((1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5))
for i in (a):
  read(i)
```

I'd expect it to do `read(1,2,3)` in the first loop, but it's returning TypeError because it's reading `(1,2,3)` as one parameter.
How should I fix this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unpack the elements using `*`

**Ex:**

```
a = ((1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5))
for i in (a):
  read(*i)
```